# Getting selected label of a select one spinner ODK

Tags: odk

I am a little stuck in displaying the selected label of a select one spinner item in another question that follows after selecting the item from the spinner. I can show the selected value of the selected item but I can't show the label of the spinner. For eg.

```
    <itext> 
        <translation lang="eng">           
          <text id="/data/HVDC:label"> 
            <value>1.1.5 गा.वि.स</value> 
          </text> 
          <text id="/data/HVDC:option0"> 
            <value>वागेश्वरी</value> 
          </text> 
          <text id="/data/HVDC:option1"> 
            <value>बनकटवा</value> 
          </text> 
............. 

<select1 appearance="minimal" ref="/data/HVDC"> 
          <label ref="jr:itext('/data/HVDC:label')"/> 
  <item> 
  <label ref="jr:itext('/data/HVDC:option0')"/> 
    <value>Bageswari</value> 
  </item> 
  <item> 
  <label ref="jr:itext('/data/HVDC:option1')"/> 
    <value>Bankatawa</value> 
  </item>   
</select1>
```

I want to show sth. like "In वागेश्वरी VDC, how many children...." in the next question when i select the first item from the spinner. I was wondering if this was possible. Please show me a direction of how to go about it.

Tried posting in ODK forums but have not heard anything from anyone yet. Any help or guidance is highly appreciated

Comment: It's not clear what you mean. Try to make shorter sentences, especially in the first paragraph.